# Is it possible to override AWS SAM policy template placeholder variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless, aws-sam

I am currently trying to add both the AWS SAM policy templates `KMSDecryptPolicy` & `KMSEnecryptPolicy` to my config yml but the KMS key is in a different account and I would need cross account access to do this.

However when using the above mentioned policy templates I can only pass the `KeyId` and not the AWS account number which is a placeholder variable.

I am trying to do this using the AWS SAM policy templates.

Would appreciate any support on this.

This is an example of how my current policies look like.

```
      Policies:
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
    - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: !Ref InvoiceFeaturesTable
    - S3CrudPolicy:
        BucketName: !Ref InvoiceFeaturesBucket
```

example code

Answer (score 0):

Both `KMSDecryptPolicy` and `KMSEnecryptPolicy` uses `${AWS::AccountId}` which defaults to the current AWS account and you cannot override it via policy templates. You ONLY can pass `KeyId`: [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#kms-decrypt-policy)

What you can simply do is to copy the policy template into your SAM template as inline policy and modify it as required. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-policies)

Comment: Thanks Pubudu! I suspected as much.